# differences in jars using maven build vs export runnable jar

Tags: spring-boot, maven

For the period that I have been using spring I have deployed jars using the export runnable jar option for which the apps seemed to run fine. I was informed that I should be deploying maven projects by doing a maven build (clean package) and deploying the jar in the target folder. I have observed differences in the outcome though. With the exported jar, it fails to find the properties file when using :

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(
```

but the maven jar reads the properties file from within the jar. Also this is a kafka consumer application and with the maven jar, I seem to have an unusual errors of kafka consumer and multi threaded errors which does not happen when running in the IDE.

My question is just to try and understand why there would be these kind of differences and what the differences are between the 2 jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Maven, the `pom.xml` defines where the resources are and what dependencies to load, for the other method (of whatever IDE?), there might be different default settings.